# Reveal div by clicking button using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function that reveals additional content by clicking a button.

I've got a script that **displays** the content by default - How do I switch it so the content is **hidden** by default and only displays when the button is clicked?

```js
function revealContent() {
  var x = document.getElementById("additionalContent");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-10 text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="revealContent()">Show More Options...</button>
</div>

<div class="col-10" id="additionalContent">
  <p>Content!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to have the style `display: none` applied by default and then toggle it. `classList.toggle` is a good use for this. You can do something like:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-10 text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="revealContent()">Show More Options...</button>
</div>

<div class="col-10 hidden" id="additionalContent">
    <p>Content!</p>
</div>

<script>
    function revealContent() {
        var x = document.getElementById("additionalContent");
        x.classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-10" id="additionalContent" style="display:none">
   <p>Content!</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: You've to add the style="display:none" to make this as default when the page is loaded.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.